# Can the optimal synthesis of a parity matrix generate complex combinations of CXs?

Tags: quantum-circuit, gate-synthesis

Consider the method described in [*Optimal Synthesis of Linear Reversible Circuits*](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=7ff18a896683d66522b54d3b3af378abb4499730).

I am led to think that, for any parity matrix given in input to such a method, the output would be a sequence of CX gates where there never occur "complex combinations".

Where with a complex combination I refer to a (KAK-)equivalence with the (i)SWAP gate.

Is my intuition correct?